# Append autocomplete elements only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a problem with my autocomplete script. It works fine everywhere except IE8. When the list is large the whole page becomes unresponsive and CPU usage goes up to almost 100% in IE8.

```
_renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        var html = "";
        if (item.NoDataFound) {
            html = "No data found";
        } else {
            if (textField.val() != "") {
                html = item.DisplayName.replace(new RegExp("(" + preg_quote(textField.val()) + ")", 'gi'), "<strong>$1</strong>"); // suggest message & Highlight matching part
            } else {
                html = item.DisplayName;
            }
        }
        return $("<li><a>" + html + "</a></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
```

Could the problem be the appendTo(ul) line, that appends every item to the ul individually. Can I somehow append the whole list only once, when the last element is reached for example?

Comment: Are you using a local data source? If so, how many items does it have in it?

Comment: About 1000 items need to be loaded. They are fetched with an ajax call.

Comment: Are they all loaded at once, or is the searching done on the server? If you are searching through 1000 items locally it is going to cause problems in IE

Comment: The server returns only the needed results. In my case there could be more than 1000 of them. Debugging my code I can see that the most time consuming tasks for IE are the _renderItem function and the _refresh function. Is there no way to optimize it for IE more, just to get as much performance out of it as possible?

Comment: The function looks pretty simple to me. I would recommend limiting the suggested results to 10 at a time. Does the user really need to see 1000 suggestions? That seems like an unmanageable list to me. Not sure what your application is though.

Comment: If I could do that I definitely would, but the user is supposed to see all those results. Maybe the function could be optimized to take the list out of the DOM, then add all the results and then add it to the DOM again, because therein lies the performance problem as far as I can tell.